# Import an excel file, rearrange the columns layout and export the new layout back to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I've created an app to help me to rearrange the columns in an excel file. The issue is that when I save the file, even if the datagridview is how I want it, the exported file is exactly like the initial file.

Can someone let me know where I'm wrong?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
namespace ReadExcelFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataSet result;
        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //==========================================================
            //CODE FOR IMPORTING DATA TO DATAGRIDVIEW===================
            //==========================================================
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    cboSheet.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        cboSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void cboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //================================================
            //CODE FOR SHEET FILTER===========================
            //================================================
            dataGridView.DataSource = result.Tables[cboSheet.SelectedIndex];
        }

        private void btnArg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //==============================================
            //CODE FOR COLUMN SORTING ======================
            //==============================================
            dataGridView.Columns["BUYER_NAME"].DisplayIndex = 0;
            dataGridView.Columns["PO_NUMBER"].DisplayIndex = 1;
            dataGridView.Columns["PO_LINE_NUMBER"].DisplayIndex = 2;
            dataGridView.Columns["VENDOR_NAME"].DisplayIndex = 3;
            dataGridView.Columns["INVOICE_NUM"].DisplayIndex = 4;
            dataGridView.Columns["INVOICE_DATE"].DisplayIndex = 5;
            dataGridView.Columns["HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE"].DisplayIndex = 6;
            dataGridView.Columns["AGING_DAYS"].DisplayIndex = 7;
            dataGridView.Columns["INVOICE_AMOUNT"].DisplayIndex = 8;
            dataGridView.Columns["INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE"].DisplayIndex = 9;
            dataGridView.Columns["INVOICE_CREATION_DATE"].DisplayIndex = 10;
            dataGridView.Columns["TERMS"].DisplayIndex = 11;
            dataGridView.Columns["BASE_AMOUNT"].DisplayIndex = 12;
            dataGridView.Columns["OU"].DisplayIndex = 13;
            dataGridView.Columns["SOURCE"].DisplayIndex = 14;
            dataGridView.Columns["STYLE_NAME"].DisplayIndex = 15;
            dataGridView.Columns["INVOICE_ID"].DisplayIndex = 16;
            dataGridView.Columns["HELD_BY"].DisplayIndex = 17;
            dataGridView.Columns["FULL_NAME_HELD_BY"].DisplayIndex = 18;
            dataGridView.Columns["CURRENT_MARKVIEW_OWNER"].DisplayIndex = 19;
            dataGridView.Columns["BUYER_ORG"].DisplayIndex = 20;
            dataGridView.Columns["LAST_UPDATED_BY"].DisplayIndex = 21;
            dataGridView.Columns["FULL_NAME_LAST_UPDATED_BY"].DisplayIndex = 22;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //================================================
            //CODE TO EXPORT DATAGRID TO EXCEL======= ========
            //================================================    
            // Creating a Excel object. 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;   
            try
            {

                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

                worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";

                int cellRowIndex = 1;
                int cellColumnIndex = 1;

                //Loop through each row and read value from each column. 
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check. 
                        if (cellRowIndex == 1)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        cellColumnIndex++;
                    }
                    cellColumnIndex = 1;
                    cellRowIndex++;
                }    
                //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user. 
                SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;    
                if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                    MessageBox.Show("Export Successful");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                excel.Quit();
                workbook = null;
                excel = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you need to achieve here other than reorganizing columns in an Excel worksheet. I question why you would use two different Excel libraries? A third party Lib to open the excel file and then you use `Interop` to save the file? It is really irrelevant to your question just wondering.

It also seems odd that you would introduce a `DataGridView` for this. If you want to re-order columns in an excel worksheet into a new excel file… simply open the excel source file, create a new excel file and copy the columns as you want. It seems unnecessary to introduce the `DataGridView` into this picture.

If you need to have the data in a `DataGridView` in order to re-order the columns (as you are) then you need to be aware of what happens when you set a `DataGridView`’s `DataSource`. When you use the line below:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = result.Tables[cboSheet.SelectedIndex];
```

The line above sets the `DataGridView`’s data source to the table selected in the combo box. When a `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataTable` the actual cells in the `DataGridView` are not really accessible as you would think. If you re-arrange the columns of the `DataGridView` (as I assume you are with the `btnArg_Click` event) the columns get changed in the `DataGridView` but the same is NOT true for the data table that the grid is bound to… it DOESN’T CHANGE. So when you loop through the `DataGridView` and address each cell like below:…

```
worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
```

This will match `i` and `j` to the DATA TABLE, and since it has not changed, you get the same excel worksheet you started with. When you change the order of `DataGridView`’s columns as I assume you are doing with the code below:

```
private void btnArg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView.Columns["BUYER_NAME"].DisplayIndex = 0;
  dataGridView.Columns["PO_NUMBER"].DisplayIndex = 1;
  .
  .
  .
```

... the indexes to the data table won’t match the index in the `DataGridView`. The data table is left alone and is not changed. Since you have conveniently set the columns `DisplayIndex` to the wanted column, then we can use this to identify which column to grab when you are creating the new excel file.

Using the `DisplayIndex` value I made (as minimal as I could) changes to your `btnSave_Click` code. It should work as expected, but I am confident there is most likely a much easier way to accomplish this. It may be easier to simply re-order the `DataTable`’s columns. Just a suggestion… probably not the best suggestion though. You may want to look at LINQ.

**Changes on the code below consist of:**
 1) added

```
excel.Visible = true;
```

to show the creation of the new excel file.

2) Added `int` variable tableCol:

```
int tableCol = -1;
```

it is used to get the current columns `DisplayIndex` to get the proper column since they have changed for the `DataGridView`.

3) Changed the 2 lines in the double for loops when writing the data to the new excel worksheet. The First line for the row headers and the second line for the data. Since you are using the same loop to get the headers, we need to decrement “i” in the second line; otherwise you will miss the first row. Again this is a hacky approach and it may be easier to simply print the headers first in a loop of its own.

```
// Headers 
worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Columns[tableCol].HeaderText;
// Data
worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Rows[i-1].Cells[tableCol].Value.ToString();
```

**Updated btn_Save event:**

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //================================================
  //CODE TO EXPORT DATAGRID TO EXCEL======= ========
  //================================================    
  // Creating a Excel object. 
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
  excel.Visible = true;

  try {
    worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
    worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";
    int cellRowIndex = 1;
    int cellColumnIndex = 1;
    int tableCol = -1;
    //Loop through each row and read value from each column. 
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView.Columns.Count; j++) {
        // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
        tableCol = dataGridView.Columns[j].DisplayIndex;
        if (cellRowIndex == 1) {
          //worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Columns[j].HeaderText;
          worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Columns[tableCol].HeaderText;
        }
        else {
          //worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
          worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView.Rows[i-1].Cells[tableCol].Value.ToString();
        }
        cellColumnIndex++;
      }
      cellColumnIndex = 1;
      cellRowIndex++;
    }
    //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user. 
    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
      workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
      MessageBox.Show("Export Successful");
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally {
    excel.Quit();
    workbook = null;
    excel = null;
  }
}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thank you, John. I will focus on using Interop and excluding DataGridView which I've added only for visual effect. As for your question about the two different Excel libraries, as I think you've noticed I'm a novice in C# and I'm inspiring from different sources, each with his one approach. Thank you for your answer!